# Empty Asp.net Core Project do not Have appsettings.json file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I Create an Asp.net Core Project But Do Not Include appsettin.json File

I edit Startup.cs File Like This:

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseStatusCodePages();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? If you're asking why there's no `appsettings.json`, that's because you chose the empty project option. If you want an `appsettings.json` file, just create one.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in `Program.cs`, you'll see the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Of particular interest is `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`, which is defined as the following:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new WebHostBuilder();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(builder.GetSetting(WebHostDefaults.ContentRootKey)))
    {
        builder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    }
    if (args != null)
    {
        builder.UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build());
    }

    builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
            if (appAssembly != null)
            {
                config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
            }
        }

        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

        if (args != null)
        {
            config.AddCommandLine(args);
        }
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        logging.AddConsole();
        logging.AddDebug();
        logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
    }).
    UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
    {
        options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
    });

    ConfigureWebDefaults(builder);

    return builder;
}
```

That's a lot of code, but pay attention to it, because it's important to understand what's happening by default.

To your primary question, a JSON config provider is added using `appsettings.json`. In other words, you don't have to add this provider directly in `Startup` because it's already added by `CreateDefaultBuilder`. The same goes with other config providers like environment variables, command-line arguments, user secrets, etc., as well as basic logging. All of that is included out of the box.